# wordpress search for only single category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a news website at index page i listed all news by categories i created 1 more category for one of my news section that is recipes now what i want is i am creating a search 
form for that section only that filter the search for only recipe category,how can i do that i wanted to know basically i created a normal search.php page as per wordpress standard code
that filter news from through out the theme.
please help me out.

here is a code in form page:

```
<div class="search_box">
           <form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">  
              <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control search-bar eng my_control" name="s" id="search" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'dastak' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/>
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="submit" class="search-submit btn my-btn" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'dastak' ); ?>">
                        <!-- <button class="btn my-btn"  id="searchsubmit"  type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> -->
                      </span>
              </div><!--input group-->

              </form> 
       </div><!--search box-->


<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement a function to catch the search but defining the category in the category__in array.

```
global $wp_query;
if(is_search()) :
    $cat = array(
        'category__in' => array(5) // Where 5 is the ID of your Music category
    );
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $cat );
endif;
query_post($args);
```

OR

You could do it this way through the hidden field - value 22 is the category

```
<form method="get" id="search form" action="/">
<div>
<input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
<input type="hidden" value="22" name="cat" id="scat" />
<input type="submit" id="search_submit" name="Search" value="Search"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook the WordPress WP_Query global instance and add whatever conditions you want.

Start reading about [preg_get_posts WordPress hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You'll find two examples about categories.

Comment: Just as a heads up, Paulo, there's a new user going through and attempting to edit all of your answers into rants against you. I've been rejecting them all, but keep an eye on your posting history in case one slips through.

Comment: @AndyM - We're watching this carefully.

Comment: @AndyM and Brad Larson, thanks a bunch. I am aware of it but I have to trust on community's policies and auto governance power.